# What does matrix decomposition really mean?

Tags: group-theory, matrices, manifolds

Any element of the symplectic group $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ can be decomposed using the [Euler decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group) into the product of three matrices.
\begin{equation}
S = O\begin{pmatrix}D & 0 \\ 0 & D^{-1}\end{pmatrix}O' \quad \quad \forall S \in Sp(2n,\mathbb{R}),
\end{equation}
where $O, O'$ are orthogonal and symplectic - $\left(\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})\cap \operatorname{O}(2n) \cong U(n)\right)$; $D$ is positive definite and diagonal.

> Does this matrix decomposition correspond to some Lie group decomposition or group manifold decomposition i.e. Cartesian product of submanifolds? In other words, what more does this tell me about the group itself and its manifold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seek a diffeomorphism from $\operatorname{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ to some product manifold. The problem with the Euler decomposition is that it is not unique whereas a diffeomorphism requires a one to one mapping.

The polar decomposition, however, does provide a unique matrix decomposition where each of the component pieces has manifold structure. This is where you will find your diffeomorphism, incidentally to $U(n) \times \mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)}$.